# how to make an input field add text after submission

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if it is possible to have an input field that has a bit of text added to it after the user enters the information they want. EX. a user types youtube.com into a search bar, and the input applies https://www.

Comment: You can do it in the form's `submit` event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an event listener that will change the value of the input field.

Use RegEx to find out if the string (`https://www.`) has been set before (for instance by copying and pasting the URL).

Here is an example:

```js
document.getElementById('url').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (!/^(https:\/\/www.)/.test(e.target.value) && e.target.value) {
    e.target.value = `https://www.${e.target.value}`;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="url">
```

Answer (score 0):

use blur event
you can run a function after a user leaves the input field

see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate the user input for that use javascript. If user presses submit button then don't submit input immediately use `event.preventDefault()` to stop default action and then change user input if needed after that manually submit it using AJAX.

```js
function manuallySubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   // manipulate  input here
   var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
   input = "changed value " + input;
   console.log(input);
   
   /* AJAX POST request
   
   let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST','location',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
    data = 'input='+(input);
    xhr.send(data);
    
    */
   // window.location.href="newlocation" if you want to redirect
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="manuallySubmit(event)" action='#' method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="input" id="input" /><br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```